# Design time error that is very annoying

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, custom-controls

i keep getting an error on many different project and it seems to happen at random. All project are WPF.

At design time it throw crystal report errors and refuse to show me the design window. at runtime everything works like a charm. any one know how to fix this ?

this is the error showing in the design window:

```
System.Reflection.Adds.UnresolvedAssemblyException
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
```

as an example, right now i am trying to work on a user control so it become VERY frustrating to have to clsoe and reopen the windows up to 25-30 times before i can see it and as when it's okay i ouch 1 to tags and bang it's gone again. "reload designer" link works 1/10 but fixing that way is certain to fail after changing 1 tag only.

here the user control code (i know people will ask for code where the error happen but it happen EVERYWHERE so i'll just give this one as it's a new one i'm just trying to build)

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomTools.UserControl.ComponentSelection.UCSelections"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
        <DataGrid >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Image Name="imgSuccesOrFail" Height="32" Width="32" Margin="10,0,10,0" >

        </Image>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Component Name : "/>
                        <Label Content="comp1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Component Name : "/>
                        <Label Content="comp1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

First thing that hit me is that i DO NOT use any visual control of crystal report neither this control has anything to do with it.

here's the CS as proof :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Drawing;


namespace CustomTools.UserControl.ComponentSelection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UCSelections.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UCSelections : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
    {
        public UCSelections()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

i've tried switching .net 4 to .net 4 client profile has i have seen post about that might be it but their problems was not same as mine exactly.

I tried compiling on : 32 bits, 64 bit and ANY CPU compile. rebuild solution.

any ideas how to solve this. and BTW i am not the only one with this problem, a couple other developer here have same issue but not necessary the same files. some user control works 100% of the time and again they don't use crystal. I know crystal is used but there is so much controls for me to know where. i haven't seen the whole scope of the projects yet.

Edit #1 :
I'll also add that the problem is extremely rare in the morning when i start working it start be more frequent the more i compile and run the different projects. but rebooting the computer doesn't help so it seems it's more coincidence that this never happened in the morning.

Edit #2 :
I open and closed the project couple time to get the error to show up and i manage to get it. now i get the following :

> Exception of type 'MS.Internal.Validate+ValidationFailure' was thrown.
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTreeManagers.DocumentNodeInfo.Insert(DocumentNode
>   item, DocumentNode after, DocumentNodeDictionary table)    at
>   MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTreeManagers.ItemUpdater.ApplyDelta(INodeHost
>   nodeHost, DeltaItemCollection delta, ModifiableDocumentTree root,
>   DocumentNodeDictionary oldTable, Boolean updateTable,
>   DocumentNodeDictionary deletedItems, Comparison`1 compare)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.DocumentTreeManager.ApplyDelta(Delta
>   delta, Comparison`1 compare)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.ViewProducerBase.ApplyUpdate(Delta
>   delta)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.ViewProducerBase.IncrementalRebuild(DocumentTreeManager
>   tree, Damage damage)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.ViewProducerBase.UpdateView(DocumentTreeManager
>   tree, Damage damage)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.ViewProducer.UpdateView(UpdateDamageArguments
>   args)

this is the same XAML/CS as describe above still. haven't touch it from yesterday since that error annoyed me very much i decided to go do something else more useful and less time wasting instead.

Edit #3 :

tried @N4TKD solution 
I only have one crystal report installed so i removed all reference to crystal report, deleted tons of controls in my projects and still have the issue. 
Then i re-checkout out the project and verify all projects assembly. they all point to `Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4. 13.0.2000.0`

anyone has the same problem ?

BTW since last edit i haven't got the error `MS.Internal.Validate+ValidationFailure` it's ONLY crystal report since.

Also getting rid of the `<image></image>` in the user control reduce the error thrown nearly to 0

Comment: Is Crystal report in you references for the project? Does the server you are connecting to have Crystal Report install? What "Design time error is [NOT] very annoying?" :)

Comment: Yes crystal is in the projects reference. It is not connecting to server it's just to generate report and using the report viewer after there is no connection on the reports. and Yes crystal report trying to run when i am NOT using it i do find that very annoying.

Comment: Remove the reference if you are not using the namespace.

Comment: i can't unfortunately. Other controls and views use's it. there over 7 years of 8 developer worth of controls ad views in that specific lib i am working on right now. new stuff is all in WPF but there is still old views and user controls that were created back on .NET 1.1 on VS 2003 i think .

Comment: Will VS 2005 maybe, then i would think you have two versions of CR and they are in conflict. My only advice remove them all and install only the one you need for your development. If you are on VS 2010 make sure you get the version for it the other versions will not work on VS 2010.

Comment: I checked out a copy of one project i removed all reference to crystal report, deleted tons of controls and still have the issue. then i re-checkout out a new version and verify all projects assembly. they all point to `Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4. 13.0.2000.0` any other idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally re-installed an older version of crystal report for VS2010 and the error is nearly not showing anymore. I've got it 2 or 3 times in the past week only which is a Great improvement over the 100-200 per day

Answer (score 2):

Try to open up another instance of visual studio, Attach the debugger to the "XdescProc", and set the debugger to break when any exception is thrown.

The process is in charge of rendereing design time views. The exceptions (or innerexceptions) can usually provide some hint on what is going on.

Comment: Unfortunately the Process XdescProc does not exist on my computer. i have tried : Automatic:native, Manage 2.0/1.1/1.0, managed 4.0, Native, Script, SilverLight, TSQL, workflow. doesn't exist anywhere. I am using VS 2010 in case process has another name.

Comment: For the record, it's XDesProc, and I'm pretty sure 2010 is called that. (I don't have it installed, so I can't actually check.)